Best way to read current balance from table when multiple processes are working simultaneously
I have an SQL Server table where Balance is being maintained like this:
Current Balance: 10000
Amount: 100

Current Balance: 9900
Amount: 50

Current Balance: 9850
Amount: 200

As you can see amount is deducted from current balance each time. I have an ASP.Net application in C# where multiple users will try to read last current balance and then update transaction in this table. What is the best way to ensure that multiple users can read correct current balance and then update transaction when accessing simultaneously?

Perhaps the best way is to use lock operator on database connection object.

Probably best to do the modification as an atomic operation. User does not need to read and update, just do it all at once UPDATE account SET balance = balance - 100

Cannot use this update statement because I also need to save history of balances.
